# Lambda function is not called when the file is uploaded to S3

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am developing a web application which uses service services from AWS. I am storing my files on the s3 bucket. What I am trying to do is when I upload the file to the S3 bucket, I want a lambda function to be automatically triggered to resize the image. I created a lambda function and test it using the console. It is working. As you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

The image is actually resized in the bucket and created as a new file as well. Then from the Laravel application, I upload an image like this.

```
$path =$request->file('file')->store(
      "path", 's3'
);
```

The image is uploaded to the s3 bucket. But the event is not triggered to create resize it. But why it is not working? Actually, that lambda function is supposed to be triggered automatically when an object is created in the bucket. But it is not working. But the function is working when I run it from the console using the test option.

What is the possible configuration I am missing to get it working? Do I need to call that lambda function manually in my code? But it is supposed to be triggered automatically when the file is uploaded. Is it? What can be the possible issue?

This is my policy on S3 Bucket:

[image]

Here is my s3 bucket event configuration

[image]

Comment: Most likely you have not setup the S3 event correctly. Go back to the example's documentation and verify that you completed each step correctly.

Comment: Do you mean this step - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-configure-event-source.html ? I followed but getting error. Please confirm me if that is what I need to follow. If it is, I will find the solution to solve the error by myself.

Comment: I added permission running this command - aws lambda add-permission as well. Not working. I followed all the steps in the tutorial. Now still not working.

Comment: Hafler. So, how come my question be more sufficient? I tried every possible way and followed every step in the tutorial as well.

Comment: `store(
      "path", 's3'
);` ... does "path" begin with `images/`?  Your trigger requires that.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much @Michael-sqlbot. That is the case. I have been struggling. I did not know that was the issue. I thought that "images" is just to specify the type of file uploaded. It worked now, That is the only issue.